# Access Timer from observation from ServerHttpObservationFilter

Tags: spring-boot, micrometer

I am trying to retrieve the total time from a `Timer` from an observation by `ServerHttpObservationFilter` using an `ObservationHandler` as below:

```
public class LogDurationObservationHandler implements ObservationHandler<ServerRequestObservationContext>, Ordered {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LogDurationObservationHandler.class);

    private final MeterRegistry meterRegistry;

    public LogDurationObservationHandler(MeterRegistry meterRegistry) {
        this.meterRegistry = meterRegistry;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supportsContext(Observation.Context context) {
        return context instanceof ServerRequestObservationContext;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop(ServerRequestObservationContext context) {
        double duration = this.meterRegistry.get(context.getName()).timer().totalTime(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        logger.error("Duration from onStop: {}", duration);
    }

    @Override
    public int getOrder() {
        return Ordered.LOWEST_PRECEDENCE;
    }

}
```

However, this raises the following error:

```
io.micrometer.core.instrument.search.MeterNotFoundException: Unable to find a meter that matches all the requirements at once. Here's what was found:
   FAIL: No meter with name 'http.server.requests' was found.
   OK: A meter with type timer was found.
    at io.micrometer.core.instrument.search.MeterNotFoundException$FromRequiredSearch.build(MeterNotFoundException.java:245) ~[micrometer-core-1.12.0-RC1.jar:1.12.0-RC1]
    at io.micrometer.core.instrument.search.MeterNotFoundException$FromRequiredSearch.access$100(MeterNotFoundException.java:49) ~[micrometer-core-1.12.0-RC1.jar:1.12.0-RC1]
    at io.micrometer.core.instrument.search.MeterNotFoundException.forSearch(MeterNotFoundException.java:46) ~[micrometer-core-1.12.0-RC1.jar:1.12.0-RC1]
    at io.micrometer.core.instrument.search.RequiredSearch.lambda$getOne$1(RequiredSearch.java:199) ~[micrometer-core-1.12.0-RC1.jar:1.12.0-RC1]
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseThrow(Optional.java:403) ~[na:na]
    at io.micrometer.core.instrument.search.RequiredSearch.getOne(RequiredSearch.java:199) ~[micrometer-core-1.12.0-RC1.jar:1.12.0-RC1]
    at io.micrometer.core.instrument.search.RequiredSearch.timer(RequiredSearch.java:120) ~[micrometer-core-1.12.0-RC1.jar:1.12.0-RC1]
    at com.example.demo.LogDurationObservationHandler.onStop(LogDurationObservationHandler.java:30) ~[main/:na]
```

Essentially I am trying to retrieve the time it took for a request from the observation that Spring Framework started/stopped. Is this possible with an `ObservationHandler` or will I need to create my own timer?

---

Using the following:

- Spring Boot 3.2.0-RC2
- Dependencies

  - `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web`
  - `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator`

The reason for doing is is because we have an existing implementation that uses a `OncePerRequestFilter` to time how long requests take. With our migration to Spring Boot 3, I thought we could replace this implementation with one based on Micrometer, specifically reusing/using the observation by Spring Framework. But I started running into the above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the issues you can face with:

1. If your handler's `onStop` is called before `DefaultMeterHandler`'s `onStop`, the `Timer` will not be there, you can verify this with a debugger
2. You are trying to find a `Timer` by its name however the name is not a unique identifier, the unique ID is the name AND all the tags.

I'm very curious about why would you want to do this but here are three solutions:

### Reuse the data that `DefaultMeterHandler` adds to the context

Try to register `ObservationTextPublisher` as a handler, it will print out the  contents of the `Observation.Context`. Or you can log it out on your own, or you can check with a debugger. You will see that the `Observation.Context` contains a `Timer.Sample` instance. This is created by `DefaultMeterHandler` at `onStart` and it contains the time when the `Timer` was started. Unfortunately that is an internal detail and you can't get this info through a public getter (please bear with me and don't think about reflection). There is another thing that you can see in the context, a `LongTaskTimer.Sample` instance. This also contains the start time and it can even tell you that. But  `LongTaskTimer.Sample` will reset at `onStop` so your `onStop` method should be before `DefaultMeterHandler`'s. The exact opposite what I told you above about the order with the `Timer`. If you are in doubt, check with a debugger.

So you should be able to do this:

```java
@Override
public void onStop(ServerRequestObservationContext context) {
    LongTaskTimer.Sample sample = context.get(LongTaskTimer.Sample.class);
    System.out.println(sample.duration(TimeUnit.SECONDS));
}
```

Again, in this case the order should be: 1. `DefaultMeterObservationHandler`, 2. your handler so that your `onStop` will be called before `DefaultMeterObservationHandler`'s `onStop`.

### Measure it on your own

This can be a rabbit hole so first of all, please read this before you try: [How Not to Measure Elapsed Time](https://develotters.com/posts/how-not-to-measure-elapsed-time/). After that you can do this:

```java
@Override
public void onStart(Context context) {
    // I recommend using an enum or class instead of a String key, something that the compiler can verify
    context.put("startTime", System.nanoTime());
}

@Override
public void onStop(Context context) {
    Long startTime = context.get("startTime");
    long duration = System.nanoTime() - startTime;
    // nanos to seconds, you can also use TimeUnit but that will round
    System.out.println(duration / 1E9);
}
```

### Use access logs of your webserver

The webservers that you can use with Spring Boot are capable of emitting logs and one of this component is the duration of processing the request. E.g.: the webserver component of [Tomcat can be configured through Boot](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto.webserver.configure-access-logs):

```
server.tomcat.accesslog.enabled=true
server.tomcat.accesslog.pattern=%t %r %s duration: %F ms
```

See the [Tomcat docs](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-10.1-doc/config/valve.html#Access_Logging) for what you can configure.
You can also [configure Logback](https://logback.qos.ch/access.html) (maybe Log4J too) to integrate with Tomcat and emit those logs (you can configure things using Logback's config system). (I have an [example project](https://github.com/jonatan-ivanov/teahouse) where I'm doing this.)

Comment: 1. Is exactly what is happening. Good to know for 2. For your first solution, I'm trying to avoid replacing or modifying the `DefaultMeterHandler` Boot registers, especially the one for tracing `TracingAwareMeterObservationHandler`. So I think solution 2 would be the one here since it aligns with our current solution using a `OncePerRequestFilter`.

Comment: I've amended the original question with the reason why.

Comment: The  first solution is not about replacing or modifying the `DefaultMeterHandler`, it's quite the opposite. The first solution depends on `DefaultMeterHandler` because it is using `LongTaskTimer.Sample` from the context that `DefaultMeterHandler` started and placed into the context.
Btw with your modified question, I have another solution/idea that might be the simplest for you, I added it to my answer.

Comment: OH, okay I understand the first one now which I think works best. We have some custom integration with our logging system (backed by Kibana/Elastic) using `logstash-logback-encoder` for JSON logging. So the final log not only includes the time taken for the request, but additional data applications can specify. This has all been very helpful, thank!